# Python: Return function list with a specific format

Tags: python, list, function, return

I have this code that is part of a Python function and now I need it to return the data in the specific format.  When I encapsulate data in the results list, I do get the data but with ['']. Is it possible to return the data in this function as specified in the data line?  I don't want Python to add extra characters.

The list coming in as data is:

```
[{u'BeginDate': u'2015-03-17T00:00:00.000-04:00', u'CreationDate': u'2015-03-16T09:24:26.000-04:00', u'NetLoadMw': 11790, u'LoadMw': 11790}]
```

The code:

```
 result =[]
 for field in data: 
     time = field['BeginDate'].split("T")[1]
     h = time.split(":")[0]  
     m = time.split(":")[1] 
     data = ddate + " " + h +":"+ m + "," + str(field['LoadMw'])
     result.append(data)
 return result
```

Output if I print data:

```
031715 00:00,11790
031715 01:00,11390
031715 02:00,11200
031715 03:00,11180
031715 04:00,11500
031715 05:00,12560
031715 06:00,14570
```

Output if I return result

```
(u'031715 00:00,11790', u'031715 01:00,11390', u'031715 02:00,11200', u'031715 03:00,11180', u'031715 04:00,11500', u'031715 05:00,12560', u'031715 06:00,14570', u'031715 07:00,15620', u'031715 08:00,15720', u'031715 09:00,15600', u'031715 10:00,15790', u'031715 11:00,15490', u'031715 12:00,15240', u'031715 13:00,14900', u'031715 14:00,14590', u'031715 15:00,14460', u'031715 16:00,14620', u'031715 17:00,15200', u'031715 18:00,15850', u'031715 19:00,16610', u'031715 20:00,16430', u'031715 21:00,15520', u'031715 22:00,14230', u'031715 23:00,13070')
```

Comment: I don't get how you have `for field in data` but `data = ddate...` in the loop body

Comment: @HaroldShip it returns an iterator which is then used, and `data` is no longer necessary to the loop. It is confusing though.

Comment: Sorry..  I am new to Python and still learning.  ddate is defined earlier in my code as 031715.  data= ddata + "" + ... and so on just puts everything in the format I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for adding the input, output, and desired output. It really helps. I think I finally understand.

Your function returns a *list* and gets printed as such.

I think what you want is to modify the return statement to this:

```python
return '\n'.join(result)
```

Or just this:

```python
print '\n'.join(result)
```

Or even this:

```python
for line in result:
  print line
```

My earlier comment about `data` meant that you are using `data` **both** as the iterator to loop through in `for field in data` and as part of the output in `data = ddate...`.